# AdMob Rewarded Video ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL for test ad

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

My rewarded video was working 2 weeks ago. I have changed nothing, my code is the same. Right now, when I try to load rewarded video ad, it gives me ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL. I know that it means there is no available ad for my app. But I am on the test device, I simply need a test ad. I created a new rewarded video ad then tried to see a test ad with its ID but the result is the same; no test ad. This system was working for almost 3 months... I was going to publish my app but now I have this problem. Any ideas how I can solve this problem ?

in OnCreate method:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "my app id");
RVA = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
RVA.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
loadRewardedAd();
```

in loadRewardedAd method:

```
RVA.loadAd("my ad id",
            new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("myphoneid")
                    .build());
```

I show rewarded ad as:

```
if (RVA.isLoaded()) {
        RVA.show();
}
```

Problem is solved by AdMob team. Everything is normal right now. There was a problem with AdMob system.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is solved by AdMob team. Everything is normal right now. There was a problem with AdMob system.

Answer (score 0):

I have this also, and the support acknowledge that they have issues serving interstitial and banner ads

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/-jOxbj7AZ_c/A79JBFPiCQAJ

so it looks like its happening at there end